# Skroll Stylesheet não funcionando

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Tenho o seguinte codigo:

#### Gem:

`gem 'skrollr-rails'`

#### Javascript:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require skrollr
//= require skrollr.menu
//= require skrollr.stylesheets
//= require_tree .
$(document).on("ready page:load", function () {
    var s = skrollr.init({
        smoothScrolling: false,
        mobileDeceleration: 0.004
    });

    skrollr.menu.init(s, {
        animate: true,
        scale: 2
    });

    s.refresh();
});
```

#### Css:

```
#foo { -skrollr-animation-name: animation1; }

@-skrollr-keyframes animation1 {
    skrollr-200 { left: 0%; }
    top { color: rgb(0, 0, 0); }
    bottom { color: rgb(255, 0, 0); }
}
```

#### Include do css:

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true, 'data-skrollr-stylesheet' => ''  %>
```

#### Html:

```
<div id="foo">fooooo</div>
```

O plugin deveria preencher as propriedades no input assim como na documentação oficial neste [LINK](https://github.com/Prinzhorn/skrollr-stylesheets#documentation) mas não está fazendo nada. O que poderia ser?
[Veja a Foto](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Je3on.png)